# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary Error while executing selenium tests in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines, nunit

[VsTest - testAssemblies error through while executing selenium UI testcases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bj8v.png)

While trying to execute selenium UI test cases through azure pipeline, the chromedriver is throwing error while execution starts. I'm using self hosted machine and unable to upgrade the chrome version on the agent.
Please share any workaround for the same.

Comment: are you sure that Chrome is actually installed on the same agent where the test runs? and what is the Chrome version? The Chrome version should match the driver version

Comment: chrome version is matching driver version which is 101.0.4951.41 but still I'm getting error cannot find chrome binary. Can you suggest any way to install chromedriver on self hosted agent through command prompt?